# WYSIWYG Editor Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I am using content builder to build a landing page. I have wraped the AmpScript block in

to hide the content of this block.

It all work fine till I enter this line.

```
IF ROWCOUNT(@SusbcriberDetailRow)<=0 THEN ENDIF
```

It stops hiding the content block from this line and it becomes visible in the display.

I am not sure why this is happening and will appreciate assistance on this.

The the rest of my code up till this line is show below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div dislpay="none" %%[ 
var @VariableSummit, @Exposed, @ForeverYoung, @Rustlers , @Jeanology, @ThunderMail, @ThunderSMS, @UTCResubscribeDate, @UTCTime, @SubscriberDetailRow,@receiveemails, @receiveemailsC, @formattedDate,,@mu_sub, @mu_subkey, @mu_statusCode, @mu_statusMsg, @errorCode,@currentSystemTime,@Previousreceiveemails,@SubscriberKey


 SET @VariableSubmit = RequestParameter("VariableSubmit") 
SET @UTCTimeReSubscribedDate = "NullValue"

    /*Checking the MasterSubcriberDE for their preferences and prefilling it */
SET @SubscriberDetailRow = LookUpRows("MasterSusbcriberDE","SubscriberKey",@SusbriberKey)
IF ROWCOUNT(@SusbcriberDetailRow)<=0 THEN ENDIF
```

And a picture of the problem: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the preview is rendered through an HTML renderer AND the browser's renderer - which usually means that anything not in a script tag will be assumed to be HTML - your < is being read as the beginning of a new tag and tripping up the renderers.  Easiest solution to ensure the scripts are hidden is to start end your scripts like so:

```
<script runat="server" language="Ampscript">

YOUR AMPSCRIPT

</script>
```

Most things inside of an actual script tag will be hidden from display.